# Datetimepicker Render Incorrectly

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I try to implement minDate properties on datetimepicker, but the date render incorrectly.

minDate : new Date()

```
$(.datepicker).datetimepicker({
   format : 'MM/DD/YYYY',
   midDate : new Date()
});
```

but the result is not in my expectation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBBos.jpg

Comment: `midDate : new Date()` Really?

Comment: I think it's `minDate: new Date()` not `midDate`. There is a typo error in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fajar-Taufik

base on your question, I give you solution is shown in below code. i try this code in my system that is works.

```
<html>
<head>

  <title>Datepicker - functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: "-1w"});

    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date('2019-08-06')
   });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code is useful to you.

Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think the problem in my datetimepicker.js file, I try to find another datetimepicker's plugin and working properly.

Answer (score 0):

not

```
midDate : new Date()
```

its

```
minDate : new Date()
```

Comment: Sorry, it's typo, I mean minDate